# Azure DNS Zone: What should I do so that my custom DNS will be used instead of the Azure DNS with IP address 168.63.129.16?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-dns

Currently, I am setting up a Hybrid Environment in Azure along with the existing Data Center.

> I have configured the Site-to-Site connection between Azure HUB-VNET & On-Prem using Virtual Gateway. Communication between Azure HUB-VNET & On-Prem is working.

I have the following Hub-Spoke model

[image]

**vnet-hub-poc-hubspoke** is the `Hub VNET` with an **Azure Firewall**

[image]

**Hub VNET** is peered with **Prod VNET**

[image]

**Prod VNET** is configured as shown below

[image]

also peered with **HUB VNET**

I have following VMs created in the **Prod VNET**

[image]

with **Routing Table** configured

[image]

I have create a DNS Zone in Azure

```
# Create DNS Zone
domainName="northeasttechnie.xyz"
az network dns zone create -g $rgName -n $domainName
az network dns record-set a add-record -g $rgName -z $domainName -n www -a $vmIP
```

**Questions:**

- What should I do so that my custom DNS will be used instead of the Azure DNS with IP address 168.63.129.16? should I update the DNS Server configuraiton at the VNET Level like mentioned below

[image]

- What should I do so that my Custom DNS will forward the queries to on On-Prem DNS?
- What should I do so that my On-Prem DNS will forward the queries to Azure DNS or DNS Server for further resolution?

Comment: The custom DNS is available to you only if you own custom domain with a registrar such as godaddy, namecheap or hostinger to mention a few.

You then have to get the public ip address and add a type `A` record with `@` as host that points to your public ip address.

I recommend you to go through this playlist on How To: Manage Custom Domains on Azure https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEPMhdsq-gNoDoIq0PhF_I56LTnAGJqy5

Especially these videos would be of help:
https://youtu.be/yzsJIqsGYi4
https://youtu.be/Dh5lzOwyVAY?t=2199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add my custom server instead of the Azure DNS with IP address 168.63.129.16 as below.

[image]

To add your custom DNS, ***Make sure you need to set up VPN before using the custom dns*** otherwise machine deployed in vnet to network from being unable to connect on-premises domain controllers.

To configure an azure vpn, In your virtual machine gateway -> point to site configuration -> authentication as active directory as below.

[image]

- For tenant Sign in with your azure ad global admin portal use the tenant id as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/`
- In azure portal -> enterprise application -> add new application -> create your own application -> azurevpn singin with azurevpn [image]

[image]

once your vpn is created in enterprise application, your azure vpn ***application id*** as ***Audience***

[image]

- Issuers as `https://sts.windows.net/<tenantID>/` and save

Then, refresh and download the vpn client in desktop and install the [azurevpnclient](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/azure-vpn-client/9NP355QT2SQB?hl=en-us&gl=us) import your downloaded file and automatically displayed the details as below.

[image]

when I tried and add my custom server it added successfully and vpn also connected like below.

[image]

[image]

Also, please check this document: [Ref1](https://anktsrkr.github.io/post/resolve-azure-internal-dns-from-your-on-prem-network/), [Ref2](https://azure.cybergav.in/azure-hybrid-dns/) & [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181776/azure-private-dns-zone-resolution-from-on-prem.html) which gives some points